# Why is my companion object cannot access method in its companion class

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala. I read that the companion object can access companion class's method. I have the following code:

```
class MinPath {
  def minPath(input : List[List[Int]], tempResult : List[List[Int]], currentlevel : Int) : List[List[Int]] = {
    ....
  }
}

object MinPath {
  ....
  def main(args : Array[String]) = {
    // This has an compile error
    val transformed =  minPath(input, List(List()), 0)
  }
}
```

They are defined in the same file called MinPath.scala.

But the minPath used in the object causes an compile error as it cannot find the minPath.

I am wondering what did I do wrong here?

Comment: Companion object is not an instance of a class, it's like a class with static methods/field, if you r from Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that the companion object can access companion class's method.

What this means is that, if `minPath` were declared with `protected` access level, `object MinPath` could still access that method. The scala compiler would not permit other classes to access it.

Currently, it has the default public access level, so access levels are not the problem here.

As AlexIv points out, you also need to create an instance of `class MinPath` in order to use the method.

```
val mp = new MinPath
val transformed = mp.minPath(input, List(List()), 0)
```

Comment: MinPath is a class, so firstly he should instantiate it and then call/import

Answer (score 6):

No one mentioned this common pattern, which obviates creating an extraneous instance:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Foo {
  def foo= 8
}
object Foo extends Foo {
  def main(args : Array[String]) = {
    Console println foo
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo
defined object Foo

scala> Foo main null
8
```

Apparently, that also works if `foo` is private, which was not obvious to me.  That is, if you extend a class to which you have private access, private symbols therein are accessible without qualification or import.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Foo {
  private def foo= 8
}
object Foo extends Foo {
  def main(args : Array[String]) = {
    Console println foo
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo
defined object Foo

scala> Foo main null
8
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `main` method, you have to call `minPath` on an instance of class `MinPath`. So you need to create an instance first:

```
object MinPath {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Create an instance
    val instance = new MinPath

    // Call the method on the instance
    val transformed = instance.minPath(input, List(List()), 0)
  }
}
```